# Terminology: "Classified in" or "Classified as"

Tags: classification, terminology

I'm working on a paper where I find that it is easier to use the phrase '... classified in ...' rather than '... classified as ...'. Is this a correct usage of the word 'classified'?

For example, would it be correct to say "This individual is classified in the same group as that individual while my dog falls into a different group" or would I need to say "This individual is classified as human. That individual is also classified as human. In this regard, they come from the same group while my dog is in a separate, mutually exclusive, group."

NOTE: Please do not try to rephrase my example as an answer. This is to illustrate the use of 'classified in' and 'classified as' *only*.

Comment: should this be off topic?

Comment: Your second example surely isn't the best example of using *as* to denote group membership.

Comment: This whole question should be classified in, as, or into the big to-do about nothing bucket (or is it an urn?).

Answer (score 2):

"Classified in" doesn't seem very idiomatic to me, but "classified into" does: "This individual is classified **into** the same group as that individual." Saying that "A is classified in B" makes it sound like B is a place where A is classified rather than a category it is classified into.

Comment: The prescriptivist injunction not to end sentences with prepositions is [offensive impertinence, up with which I will not put](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html).

Comment: Very well :) In the spirit of your example, though, the term "put up with" is an example of a confusing multi-word idiom (with prepositions) when something like "stand" or "tolerate" would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be almost exclusively to use **as** for any language about group membership rather than **in**, **within**, or **into**. The latter reminds me of urn models, and treats the group construct as an actual physical thing into which people can actually be placed. On the other hand, **as** denotes a label assignment and things or people with that label are somehow similar or equivalent. In fact the etymology of **as** comes from old English meaning "similarly".

This is an important distinction, because falling **into** a group doesn't necessarily convey that individuals **within** that group are in any way more similar than other individuals **in** other groups.

For instance, if you're **in** a rock band, you probably play a different instrument and have different skills than other members of your band. But, you would be classified **as** a bass guitarist because anyone else who **is** a bass guitarist shares more in common with you than others **in** their respective bands.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> This individual is classified with the same group as that individual,
>   while my dog (falls into) is classified with a different group

"classified as" is used to describe the quality of a matter or person (in a formal, technical or scientific way), for example "this chemical is classified as toxic/as a weapon" or, maybe more formal, "a person is classified as (considered as) sick/a disease carrier"

"classified in" sounds strange, whereas, to me, "classified into" demands plural subject and object: " they are classified into three groups"

somebody correct me if I'm wrong